# Disable Advanced Tab in TinyMCE

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform, tinymce, editor

I need to change the settings for the image upload dialog in TinyMCE to remove the  Advanced Tab.

[image: Advanced tab in Upload image dialog of TingMCE]

I've already changed settings of the tool bar icons successfully by creating:

```
<type name="\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config">
    <plugin name="add_wysiwyg_data" type="\Hidden\System\Plugin\WysiwygConfig" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

and

```
namespace Hidden\System\Plugin;

class WysiwygConfig
{
    public function afterGetConfig($subject, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $config)
    {
        $styleArray = [
            'Hero - Image' => 'hero__image',
            'Hero - Heading' => 'hero__heading',
            'Hero - Action Button' => 'hero__primary-action'
        ];

        $styles = array_map(function ($title, $class) {
            return "{$title}={$class}; ";
        }, array_keys($styleArray), array_values($styleArray));

        $config->addData(
            ["settings" =>
                ["theme_advanced_styles" => implode("; ", $styles),
                    "theme_advanced_buttons1" => "magentovairable,magentowidget,styleselect,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,link,unlink,anchor,image",
                    "theme_advanced_buttons2" => "undo,redo,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,search,replace,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,removeformat,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,|,fullscreen",
                    "theme_advanced_buttons3" => "",
                    "theme_advanced_buttons4" => ""]]);

        $config->addData(["image_dimensions" => false]);
        $config->addData(["image_advtab" => false]);

        return $config;
    }
```

As you can see I have tried to add the config data to disable image_dimensions and image_advtab but to no effect, I have also tried having this as elements of the previous *$config->addData* (under *settings*).

I got [these settings](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) [from this documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x//reference/Configuration3x/), but the docs for the version of TinyMCE in Magento 2 aren't that great.

I think I must be barking completely up the wrong tree, how can I disable this tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way to disable tab:

You can find config values here:

```
/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Config.php
```

If you want to disable it you can modify HTML file.

Path: `/lib/web/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/image.htm`

Line 20:

```
<li id="advanced_tab" aria-controls="advanced_panel"><span><a href="javascript:mcTabs.displayTab('advanced_tab','advanced_panel');" onmousedown="return false;">{#advimage_dlg.tab_advanced}</a></span></li>
```

Comment this code.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad I can stop chasing something! Hacking it in the core is not ideal, but necessary in this case.